How do I get the link to my running Flask Server in Pterodactyl Panel
I would like to know is there any way to know to what url did my python flask app get deployed to in my Pterodactyl Panel? If there is any way, how do I access my running flask app? I would like to know the steps on how to access a Flask App hosted in Pterodactyl.
I've tried setting my app to "0.0.0.0" and then tried using the given "hostname:port" in the "Network" tab, but it doesn't seem to respond. Any guidance or any information would be appreciated!
